# Python, как динамически вызвать метод из класса

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть класс:

```
class Python:
  def method(self, a):
    pass

python_instance = Python()
```

Хочу сделать так:

```
dynamic_method = "method"
python_instance[dynamic_method]("test")
```

Как такое провернуть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это довольно просто. Сначала получаем ссылку на метод экземпляра класса при помощи `getattr()`, а потом просто зовём этот метод по полученной ссылке.

```
class Python:
  def method(self, a):
    print(a)

python_instance = Python()

dynamic_method = "method"
getattr(python_instance, dynamic_method)("test")
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так

```py
class Python:
    def method(self, a):
        print(a)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return getattr(self, index)

ins = Python()
mymethod = "method"
ins[mymethod]("test")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вроде все банально просто.